# Advice on connecting RO filter system

Tags: plumbing, faucet, connectors

My kitchen faucet water pipes are pretty high and close to the sink. I'm not sure if it was done on purpose to have more space at the bottom of the cabinet or a miscalculation. In order to install the RO system I have I need to connect a T type water feed adapter, which according to installation manual needs to be connected directly to the valve. Then the faucet hose is reconnected at the top and another plastic hose would be connected to the side to feed the filtering system. Because I don't have the space to connect the adapter vertically I think I need some kind of a 90 degree elbow to connect to the valve first, however I'm having trouble finding anything that would work here. I think it needs to have a swivel type connection on one end and just a male thread on the other. Any suggestion on where to get something like this or perhaps another way to solve the problem? Thanks for any input.

[image][image]

Comment: For a 90 degree turn there the part you want is called a street elbow. (If it isn't immediately obvious you can turn the entire elbow to thread it on, so there's no need for any moving parts.)

Comment: thanks, but after the elbow is tightened there's no guarantee that it will end up in the direction I need. Or is there a way to ensure that it does?

Comment: The tape makes the joint water tight, the threads hold the fitting on. Once you snug it up you can either stop short of super tight or tighten it a bit more to get the correct orientation. If you look at a gas line as an example all of the fittings are threaded, and in the correct orientation. You should hold the shutoff with a second wrench though, to prevent damaging the existing work while you're cranking on new.

Comment: Have you considered a short hose from the valve to the T and mounting the T or hose the the cabinet back wall?